# Question about the duality between 2+1 d transverse-field Ising model (TFIM) and $\mathbb{Z}_2$ gauge theory

Tags: condensed-matter, ising-model, duality

I was reading McGreevy's Lecture notes [Where do QFTs come from?](https://mcgreevy.physics.ucsd.edu/s14/239a-lectures.pdf)
, and on chapter 5 he talks about a duality between the $2+1d$ transverse-field Ising model (TFIM) and the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ gauge theory, where the two Hamiltonian are identified
\begin{align}
 H_{Ising}=-\sum_{<ij>}Z_iZ_j-g\sum_i X_i \hspace{2mm}\leftrightarrow \hspace{2mm} H_{\mathbb{Z_2}}=-\sum_l\tau^x_l-g\sum_p \prod_{l\in p}\tau^z_l
\end{align}
through the change of variables
\begin{align}
Z_iZ_j\leftrightarrow \tau^x_l,
\hspace{2mm}
X_i\leftrightarrow \prod_{l\in p}\tau^z_l.
\end{align}

However, I was wondering if there exists an operator which implements this duality in the same fashion as the Kramer-Wannier duality is implemented in the case $1+1 d$ TFIM. By that I mean that the operator
\begin{align}
U_{KM}\equiv\prod_{i=1}^{N-1}\left(\frac{1+iX_i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\left(\frac{1+iZ_iZ_{i+1}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\left(\frac{1+iX_N}{\sqrt{2}}\right)
\end{align}
provides the following maps for $i\neq N$
\begin{align}
U_{KM} (X_i) U^{-1}_{KM}&=Z_iZ_{i+1}
\\
U_{KM} (Z_iZ_{i+1})U^{-1}_{KM}&=X_i.
\end{align}

Does anyone know if such operator does even exists?

Comment: H_Ising and H_Z2 do not live in the same Hilbert space, right? Would you be fine if one adds some trivial qubits to H_Ising before performing the unitary?

Comment: Yes, I would fine with that. In fact, think there is no way of avoiding this trivial qubits in what I am trying to do, since there are more links than sites on the lattice.